# How to do conditional xml serialization based on generic list property

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have following classes

```
public class Books
{
    public Books()
    {
        BookList = new List<Book>();
    }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public List<Book> BookList { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeBookList(){
        -- serialize only when the particular book selected property is true--
    }
}

public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Consider I have three books with title t1,t2,t3. But only t1 and t3 are selected.

So how can I serialize this class into the following xml based on Selected property of each book?

`<Books>
     <Book Title="t1" />
     <Book Title="t3" />
 </Books>`

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to add filter that you can customize according to any filtering rules. Looking at your flag is a special case usage.
The explanations in the code comments:

```
public class Books
    {
        public Books()
        {

        }

        // apply this function each time befor doing serialization
        public void RunBeforeSerialization(Func<Book, bool> filter)
        {
            booksFilter = filter;
        }

        // this is the filter that you set before serialization
        Func<Book, bool> booksFilter = null;

        public string Customer { get; set; }

        List<Book> bookList = new List<Book>();
        public List<Book> BookList
        {
            get
            {
                if (booksFilter == null) // the regular property usage
                {
                    return bookList;
                }
                else // used when serialize
                {
                    var temp = from book in bookList
                              where booksFilter(book) // applying the filter
                              select book;

                    var res = temp.ToList();
                    booksFilter = null;
                    return res;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                bookList = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the Main function:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Books books = new Books() { Customer = "Allan" };
            books.BookList.Add(new Book() { Title = "T1", Selected = true });
            books.BookList.Add(new Book() { Title = "T2", Selected = false });
            books.BookList.Add(new Book() { Title = "T3", Selected = true });

            // here you add the filter that used when serialized
            books.RunBeforeSerialization(b => b.Selected == true);

            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Books));
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            ser.Serialize(sw, books);

            Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

You can thing about any other way how to set the filtering, but the main idea here is that you give the user the option to control what will be returned during serialization, without harming the regular property usage.